# Overflow-x: auto; в overflow с border-radius, в конечном итоге на android неправильно отображается

Tags: html, css, css3

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на android отображается неправильно overflow с border-radius, в классе block_bl нет закруглений когда внутри блока есть блок с прокруткой. На ios все норм и на пк тоже. Пробовал -webkit-mask-image(svg и png) - результат есть, но в итоге все шрифты размытые(наблюдается на устройстве android более 300dpi, на ios - гуд). Пробовал ставить border-radius классу overflow_l, но на android ползунок прокрутки не скрывается. Может есть какие-то предложения? Заранее спасибо.

Пример: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1x2e6x9/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700&subset=cyrillic');

* {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
 color: #ACACAC; 
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.block_bl {
 display: block;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden; 
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}

.block_bl .overflow_l {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.block_bl .overflow_l:before, .block_bl .overflow_l:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20px;
 z-index: 20;
}

.block_bl .overflow_l:before {
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(43%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
}

.block_bl .overflow_l:after {
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(57%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
}

.block_bl .overflow_l > div {
 display: block;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-x: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0 20px;
 height: 62px;
 font-size: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 100%;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 0 15px;
 color: #2F2F2F;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li:first-child a {
 padding-left: 0;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active a {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2F2F2F !important;
 background: #FFF;
 height: 42px;
 line-height: 41px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 margin: 9px 6px 0 6px;
 border-radius: 23px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
 -moz-border-radius: 23px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.11), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.11), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.11), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active:first-child a {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active:last-child a {
 margin-right: 0;
}

.block_bl ul.admin_links li a:hover {
 color: #B1B1B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_bl">
    <div class="overflow_l">
     <div>
      <ul class="admin_links">
       <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Сайты</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш текущий код не обрезается бордер-радиусом без оверфлоу хидден потому что сверху у вас наложены псевдоэлементы (пока что мне, правда, непонятно зачем они нужны). Необходимо задать псевдоэлементам соответствующие радиусы и для `.block_bl` `overflow: hidden` можно убирать.

Кстати, использовать вендорные префиксы для `border-radius`, `box-sizing` и `box-shadow` уже давно не надо, а `linear-gradient` достаточно писать в 4 строчки для очень широкой поддержки.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700&subset=cyrillic');
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
a {
  color: #ACACAC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.block_bl {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
.block_bl .overflow_l {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.block_bl .overflow_l:before,
.block_bl .overflow_l:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}
.block_bl .overflow_l:before {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
}
.block_bl .overflow_l:after {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
}
.block_bl .overflow_l > div {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #2F2F2F;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2F2F2F !important;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 41px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 9px 6px 0 6px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active:first-child a {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li.active:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.block_bl ul.admin_links li a:hover {
  color: #B1B1B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_bl">
  <div class="overflow_l">
    <div>
      <ul class="admin_links">
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Сайты</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Форум</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Новости</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```